# Printer Permission in RDS envirement

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, network-printer

I have a problem in the print management in a multi-site environment, where all users use remote desktop sessions on a HQ server (Win2012R2).

All printers are network printers, installed with TCP/IP protocol on a print server (Win2012R2), in HQ, with the RDS Server.

I need to prevent users to print on printers in other locations, but only on printers in their seats.

How do I set permissions on printers, printer server or RDS Server to make sure that users in site A, don't use printers in site B?

Answer (score 0):

(I know that this is an old thread...) First of all to distinct users form different locations users must be added to different groups in Active Directory. You should create those groups. When you have users in different groups you can assign them to printers and give them different permissions. Every printer on a print server in properties window has a tab Security, from there you can manage permissions for different users or groups (you can give your users/groups permission to Print, Manage Printers, Manage Documents and give them Special Permissions). If you have group Everyone there you should delete it and replace with an appropiate group of your choice.